# Undefined element when tab is not active

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

When I try to access a son of a Tab element, if it is not active QML throws an error saying is `undefined`.

*main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

    ApplicationWindow {
        TabView {
            Tab {
                id: mytab1
            }
            Tab {
                id: myTab2
                Rectangle {
                    //(...)
                }
            }
        }

        Connections {
            target: eventManager

            onData: {
                var scene = myTab2.children[0];
                console.log(scene);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, if myTab2 is active, I can see in the console `QQuickItem_QML_15(0x27f1e2e0)`. If myTab2 is not active, then qml throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`.

Why is undefined if the tab is not active and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tab.html) website, I've found a solution.

> Tabs are lazily loaded; only tabs that have been made current (for
>   example, by clicking on them) will have valid content. You can force
>   loading of tabs by setting the active property to true:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    TabView {
        Tab {
            id: mytab1
            active: true
        }
        Tab {
            id: myTab2
            active: true
            Rectangle {
                //(...)
            }
        }
    }

    Connections {
        target: eventManager

        onData: {
            var scene = myTab2.children[0];
            console.log(scene);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I've added the property `active: true` in both tabs, and It works fine!

Answer (score 2):

A `TabView` doesn't create its content items until a tab is activated.

Your example begins at tab 1, at this point the rectangle in tab 2 doesn't exist, so you get `undefined`. If you activate tab 2 the rectangle will be created, and then if you go back to tab 1 you will not get `undefined`.

A `Tab` inherits a `Loader`, and comes with an `active` property. I suppose there is an optimization that exists back in the `Loader` component to delay loading until the element becomes visible. If you set `active: true` in your `Tab` it will be loaded before the tab is activated. Note that this will not make the tab view open with the second tab active.

```
Tab {
    id: t2
    active: true
    Rectangle {
    }
}
```